# Question about numerical range of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to solve the following question, but I did not reach to any answer, I would be so glad if anyone could help me on that.

Let $E$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ be  an operator. It is well known that the numerical range of $T$
$$W(T)=\{\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in E,\;\;\|x\|=1\},$$
is convex. If $\lambda=\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle\in W(T)$, and $\mu=\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(T)$, where $\|x_1\|=\|y_1\|=1$. Why for any point $\eta$ on the line segment joining $\lambda$ and $\mu$, there exist complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\|\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\|=1$ and $\langle T (\alpha x_1+\beta y_1)\; |\;\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\rangle=\eta.$ ??

I try as follows:

Let $M$ be a subspace spanned by $x_1$ and $y_1$ and $P_{M}$ be a projection of $E$ onto ${M}$. Consider $S=P_{M}TP_{M}$. We deduce that $\langle S x_1\; |\;x_n\rangle=\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle$ and $\langle S y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle=\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle$. Hence, $\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle,\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(S)=\{\langle Sx\;|\;x\rangle=\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in M,\;\;\|x\|=1\},$ which is convex. As a consequence, any point $\eta$ on the line segment joining $\lambda$ and $\mu$ belongs to $W(S)$. So, there exist $z\in M$ such that $\|z\|=1$ and $\langle Tz\; |\;z\rangle=\eta$. This implies that there exist complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\|\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\|=1$ and $\langle T (\alpha x_1+\beta y_1)\; |\;\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\rangle=\eta.$

But why
$$W(S)=\{\langle Sx\;|\;x\rangle=\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in M,\;\;\|x\|=1\}?$$

Thank you everyone !!

Comment: Your statement is overly complicated. You just need to say operator, no need for the algebra. And why the subscripts on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: If $P$ is the projection onto the space spanned by $x$ and $y$ then I think you can reduce the problem to considering the operator $Q=PTP$ in the two dimensional space.

Comment: Let $M$ be a subspace spanned by $x_1$ and $y_1$ and $P_{M}$ be a projection of $E$ onto ${M}$. Consider $S=P_{M}TP_{M}$. We deduce that $\langle S x_1\; |\;x_n\rangle=\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle$ and $\langle S y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle=\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle$. Hence, $\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle,\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(S)$ which is convex. ِCould you please help me to end the proof? Thank you

Comment: You have two equations in $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: I'm very  sorry, I don't  understand

Comment: Maybe you don't need the equations. Does the result hold for any $\eta \in /W(S)$ ? That seems too easy.

Comment: Let $M$ be a subspace spanned by $x_1$ and $y_1$ and $P_{M}$ be a projection of $E$ onto ${M}$. Consider $S=P_{M}TP_{M}$. We deduce that $\langle S x_1\; |\;x_n\rangle=\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle$ and $\langle S y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle=\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle$. Hence, $\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle,\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(S)$ which is convex. As a consequence every $\eta$ on the line segment joining $\lambda$ and $\mu$, there $z$ such that $\|z\|=1$ and $\langle S z\; |\;z\rangle=\langle T z\; |\;z\rangle=\eta.$ But why $z$ has the form $\alpha x_1+\beta y_1$? And thank you

Comment: $\eta \in W(S)$ means there is a unit vector $z \in M$ such that $\langle Sz,z \rangle = \eta $. But any $z \in M$ is of the form $\alpha x + \beta y$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you very  much. I hope that you write the  comment as an answer.

Comment: Is what I write correct?....Hence, $\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle,\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(S)=\{\langle Sx\;|\;x\rangle=\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in M,\;\;\|x\|=1\},$ which is convex. As a consequence, any point $\eta$ on the line segment joining $\lambda$ and $\mu$ belongs to $W(S)$. So, there exist $z\in M$ such that $\|z\|=1$ and $\langle Tz\; |\;z\rangle=\eta$. This implies that there exist complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\|\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\|=1$ and $\langle T (\alpha x_1+\beta y_1)\; |\;\alpha x_1+\beta y_1\rangle=\eta.$ I can write it as an answer?

Comment: As you can see from the above, I'm not an expert in this area, so you can tell as well as I can. I think you should edit your question to remove the unnecessary complications.

Comment: What are the  complication in  my question?

Comment: What I mentioned in my first comment. Just a small point, but I see this sort of thing quite often in Questions. I think this makes people less likely to read or answer them.

Comment: Are $x_1$ or $y_1$ nonzero? The statement as it stands is false when $x_1=y_1=0$.

Comment: Surely non zero  because there are two unit vectors.

Comment: No. That $W(T)$ is made up of the values of $\langle Tu,u\rangle$ for all unit vectors $u$ doesn't imply that $x$ is a unit vector whenever $\langle Tx,x\rangle\in W(T)$.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not evident but not difficult to prove. It is (also) known as the Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem for linear operators. One of the shortest proofs I have seen is one page by [K Gustafson](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-01/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9.pdf)

As you are sort of hinting at it suffices to look at the (possibly complex) plane spanned by unit vectors $x$ and $y$ in order to find for any $0<\lambda<1$ a unit element $z=\alpha x + \beta y$ so that $$(Tz|z) = \lambda (Tx|x) + (1-\lambda) (Ty|y)$$
The construction of $\alpha,\beta$ is, however, not completely trivial but you better look at the above reference (which is open access), rather than I reproduce it here.

Regarding $W(S)$ (if I understand your question correctly): Provided $P=P_M$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$, indeed $(Sx|x)=(Tx|x)$ for all $x\in M$. This follows from $P^2=P^*=P$ and $Px=x$ for $x\in M$ so that for such $x$:
  $$ (Sx|x)=(PTPx|x)=(PTx|x)=(Tx|P^*x)=(Tx|Px)=(Tx|x).$$
On the other hand it does not simplify the problem since showing that $W(S)$ is convex is as hard (or easy depending on taste) as showing that $W(T)$ is convex, since the latter in any case is a 2-dimensional problem (as you will realize by looking in the above reference).

Comment: Thank you but I want to know if it is true that $W(S)=\{\langle Sx\;|\;x\rangle=\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in M,\;\;\|x\|=1\}?$

Comment: Thank you but perhaps you have not understand very well my question. Please see the following answer

Comment: Let $M$ be a subspace spanned by $x_1$ and $y_1$ and $P_{M}$ be a projection of $E$ onto ${M}$. Consider $S=P_{M}TP_{M}$. We deduce that $\langle S x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle=\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle$ and $\langle S y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle=\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle$. Hence, $\langle T x_1\; |\;x_1\rangle,\langle T y_1\; |\;y_1\rangle\in W(S)$ which is convex. As a consequence every $\eta$ on the line segment joining $\lambda$ and $\mu$, there $z$ such that $\|z\|=1$ and $\langle S z\; |\;z\rangle=\langle T z\; |\;z\rangle=\eta.$ But why $z$ has the form $\alpha x_1+\beta y_1$?

Comment: For a general projection the result is false (note that $T$ may map a point in $M$ outside of $M$). For an orthogonal projection it is true (as I showed). You say that $W(S)$ is convex, but to show this is the same work as showing $W(T)$ is convex. In fact to show that there is $z$ of the form $z=\alpha x_1 + \beta y_1$ is not evident but precisely what is done in the reference I gave. I think you should really take a look and try to understand the proof, it has to do with intersection of conics.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, that's a pleasant read.

Comment: I think that the proof of the Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem for linear operators don't require that $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space. i.e. we don't need the hypothesis that $\mathcal{H}$ is complete. Do you agree with me? Thank you very much

Comment: @Student Yes, a pre-Hilbert space suffices for this result (as also stated in the cited reference).

Comment: @Student Sorry. I don't know that one. My guess is that it may not be true (but that's just a guess).

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I think that in proof of the Toeplitz-Hausdorff's Theorem we don't require that $T$ is continuous, it is just a linear map. Do you agree with me? Thank you very much

Comment: @Student : Yes, that seems correct. All you need is that given two vectors in the domain of the operator, their complex span is in the domain and the operator is linear on this two-dimensional subspace.